# Motion Webserver not working

Tags: webcam

So, I've installed Motion on ubuntu 12.10, and it seems to be working, for the most part. The /tmp/motion directory is filling with images... so far, so good...

However, the built in webserver isn't working as I'd expect. If I visit localhost or the IP of the machine, I just get a holding page. The webserver is apparently working on port 8081 (the default) but just serving a white page saying there's no content as yet.

Here's my motion.conf: http://hastebin.com/lotiniwavo.vala

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work on Chrome for me as well.  However, firefox is not an issue. You can also use VLC locally to view the stream or on your cell provided it's connected to the same LAN.  Chrome may be trying to connect to https://localhost instead of http://localhost.

Answer (score 1):

This was a non-issue.

The software was working perfectly, it's simply Chrome that can't handle being served a raw MJPEG stream. If you embed it in a webpage's `<img>` tag or use Firefox, the webcam serves a stream as expected.

Comment: Also, Internet Explorer, of any version, can't handle MJPEG in either case.